# Download/clone single file from git via jenkins declaritive pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to download/clone a properties file to my Jenkins workspace and read it.

jenkins pipeline syntax provides the following step but it clones the whole repo, which is big and unnecessary in my use case.

```
git credentialsId: 'github-app-for-clone', url: 'https://github.com/abc-internal/test-repo.git'
```

my test-repo consists of extract.yml which I need to copy on my Jenkins workspace and then read it in further stages.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't clone a part of the repo, what you can do is directly download the file you need. You can use a script like below in your Pipeline to do it. If you don't want to use Groovy for this, you can simply use something like `curl` as well.

**If it's a public repo.**

```
def content = new URL ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxx/sample/main/testdir/hosts").getText()
```

**If it's a Private repo**

When you are calling a private repo, you need to send a Basic Auth header with the access token. So use the following groovy script instead.

```
def accessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
def get = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxx/something/hosts").openConnection();
get.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Basic " + accessToken)
def content = get.getInputStream().getText()
```

---

Complete Pipeline.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('GetFile') {
      steps {
          script {
            def accessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
            def get = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxx/something/hosts").openConnection();
            get.setRequestProperty("authorization", "Basic " + accessToken)
            def content = get.getInputStream().getText()

            def fileYaml = readYaml text: content
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so do i need to add private repo code in Jenkins pipeline steps?? what would be the location to read this file from? since this is a yml file, can i use https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/  readYml ??

Comment: also, i found following fileoperations, https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/file-operations/#file-operations-plugin. will fileDownloadOperations work in this case?

Comment: @deewreck check the updated answer. If you can pass credentials in `file operations` plugin you should be able to use it.